# pcap_lookupdev undefined

Tags: c++, pcap, sniffing, network-security

I am developing for OSX 10.8.  I just installed `libpcap` via MacPorts and tried running a simple device hunter (below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *dev, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if(dev == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
        return(2);
    }

    printf("Device %s\n", dev);
    return(0);
}
```

and while trying to compile with g++ i am getting:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcap_lookupdev", referenced from:
      _main in ccIMp1m2.o
```

Any helpful advice so I can actually get started with learning this stuff would be great! I googled for a solid 10-15 minutes but just couldn't find much on my particular issue with my setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to link `libpcap`.  Probably `-lpcap` added to your compiler command line will work.  If it's installed somewhere strange (and it might be, since you got it from MacPorts), you might need `-L/path/to/libpcap -lpcap`.

Comment: that did it. thanks. Walkthroughs never include simple stuff like this. humph. lol I guess it's just assumed I would know better